# How to handle list of MultipartFiles within custom object via REST API?

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, postman

Within my request data object I have primitive variables and:

```
data class ItemRequest(
    // ...

    @field:Size(min = 0, max = 5)
    val photoFiles: MutableList<PhotoFile> = mutableListOf()
)
```

Now **PhotoFile** is described as:

```
data class PhotoFile(
    val id: String? = null,
    val file: MultipartFile? = null
)
```

To accept an API request I have the following controller method:

```
@PostMapping
fun createItem(@Valid @ModelAttribute itemRequest: ItemRequest) {
    // ...
}
```

Now to test the functionality I use [Postman](https://www.postman.com/) and for the body I provide **form-data** with the following key-value pairs (I emit unnecessary data):

| Key | Type | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| photoFiles[0]id | Text | 1 |
| photoFiles[0]file | File | /C:/.../mountain.jpg |

Sending this **POST** request results with the following error:

> Resolved
> [org.springframework.web.bind.MethodArgumentNotValidException:
> Validation failed for argument [0] in public
> org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<java.lang.String>
> createItem(itemRequest) with 2 errors: default message [Failed to
> convert property value of type
> 'org.springframework.web.multipart.support.StandardMultipartHttpServletRequest$StandardMultipartFile'
> to required type; Cannot convert value of type
> 'org.springframework.web.multipart.support.StandardMultipartHttpServletRequest$StandardMultipartFile'
> to required type 'PhotoFile' for property 'photoFiles[0]': no matching
> editors or conversion strategy found]] ]

When **PhotoFile** contains only **id**, or when I move **val file: MultipartFile** straight to the **ItemRequest** class everything works fine.

So my question would be how to solve this issue or would there be a better approach for me to accepts these photos with corresponding IDs? I would not prefer base64. Thanks.